# How to setup forward secrecy in nginx so that iOS9 (Xcode7) app with default ATS settings can connect to my server?

Tags: ios, ssl, nginx, ios9

iOS9's App Transport Security states that connections that do not meet certain requirements will fail.  Below are the requirements quoted from Apple's document (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html)

- The server must support at least Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol version 1.2.
- Connection ciphers are limited to those that provide forward secrecy (see the list of ciphers below.)
- Certificates must be signed using a SHA256 or greater signature hash algorithm, with either a 2048-bit or greater RSA key or a 256-bit or greater Elliptic-Curve (ECC) key.

I've checked that my server is indeed using a certificate with 2048-bit RSA key and signed using SHA256 hash algorithm.  Anyhow, my Xcode7-built app failed to connect to my server with default ATS setting.  After I set `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` to `NO` in the app's `Info.plist`, however, the connection succeeded.  So it looks like that my server isn't correctly configured with forward secrecy ciphers.  Below is my current setting in nginx.conf:

```
ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers               'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
```

My certificate is issued by Comodo and the setting I used above is also from Comodo's support document (https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/certificate-installation-nginx).

According to Apple's document, with default ATS settings, accepted ciphers include:

- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

(It seems that my nginx's ssl_ciphers setting has these ciphers.)

And if `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` is set to `NO` in the app's settings, following ciphers will also be accepted:

- LS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

With this set to `NO`, my app connects successfully to my server, though the reason remains unknown to me.

So my question is, how should I setup nginx for forward secrecy ciphers so that iOS9 (Xcode7) app with default ATS settings can connect successfully?

---

UPDATED:

With the suggestion given by @keno, I reconfigured my server following the guide from https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html.  I regenerate a new DH group with the following command:

```
openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048
```

and added it in my nginx configuration:

```
ssl_dhparam dhparams.pem;
```

But the connection from my app still fails.  The `nsurl --ats-diagnostics` tool still indicates that the problem is caused by forward secrecy.

---

For diagnosis purpose, below is the **ssltest** result page screenshot of my server given by [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `nginx/1.0.15` in October 2015 (based on your Qualys screenshot), for a new deployment, a version which has been released in April 2012, as the final maintenance release of the 1.0 series?

Although https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-enabling-perfect-forward-secrecy.htm#nginx_forward_secrecy and https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy claim that nginx `1.0.6+` is the minimum required nginx version for forward secrecy, it might as well be that your SSL version isn't so lucky to be OpenSSL `1.0.1c+` as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that my `nginx` is way out-of-date.  I will try updating it to see if it fixes the problem.  FYI, I'm using `OpenSSL` 1.0.1e.

Comment: @goodbyeera, I would recommend you update both nginx and OpenSSL (or, better yet, switch to LibreSSL); you're currently using just about the minimally required (and certainly unsupported) versions for forward secrecy, it's not too surprising that they have minimal support for forward secrecy, maybe only for certain browsers as the SSL screenshot you've provided appears to claim

Answer (score 3):

Nginx needs DHE key-exchange which you are probably missing

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096
```

and then add it to the config file with the rest of SSL configuration

```
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

i have same setup (ios9 + nginx) just with different ciphers, and it's working, you can always check you server ssl configuration on this site [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/) (great site, you should aim for A+)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I regenerated a new DH group and added it in my nginx configuration, but the connection still fails.  See my update to the question.

Comment: I updated my original question with the ssltest result page screenshot from ssllabs.com, in case it could provide more information of what is wrong with my server's forward secrecy setting.

Comment: It's maybe cipher problem because forward secrecy seems to work for you with some browsers , here you have gist with configuration that i'm using, you can try it out if it helps. https://gist.github.com/ztepsa/f1507a955940f2f742ba

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your configuration.  Anyhow, the situation remains the same after adopting your configuration on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or commenting out `ssl_ciphers` line from your `nginx.conf` to see if the defaults would work.

If they do, start with the following line that gives `A+` at SSL Report and `Forward Secrecy: With modern browsers` marked.

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!LOW:!RC4;
```

Full list of ciphers your openssl has can be seen from:

```
openssl ciphers | sed s/:/\\n/g
```